# Javascript closures problem

Tags: javascript, events, closures

I have some inherited JS code that uses this format:

```
function main(param) {
  var myVar;

  function doSomething() {
     ...
  }

  ....
  doSomething();
  ....
}
```

It works, but now I have to control some click events. Something like this:

```
function main(param) {
  var myVar;

  function manageEvent(item) {
     ...
     myVar = item.value;
     ...
  }

  ....
  item.onclick = function() { manageEvent(this) }
  ....
}
```

The problem is that manageEvent() **has no access** to *myVar* and I don't know how to solve the problem without rewriting all the code (really hard work). How can I manage the event in order to give "manageEvent" access to *myVar*?

Comment: Your code should work fine.

Comment: What's the actual error you are seeing? In your example manageEvent does have access to myVar.

Comment: When I call main() for first time it works, but when I call main() for second time myVar has the previous value when exit from manageEvent :(

Comment: maybe just try nullifying your myVar when it's declared? var myVar = null;

Comment: calling main multiple times binds the click event handler multiple times. You probably don't want this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/kgmYM/

Your problem is somewhere else, it certainly is not in this code; it's perfectly fine. Try and see if what you're clicking actually has the same value; try and play with its value and see the result. But anyway, your posted code works, and without any further information, we can't find what's really wrong in your situation.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask more. It's a real pain in the ass to find a logical error. Spent about 5 hours one time throwing my head against the wall why a function infinitely calls itself and crashes everything, and discovered I missed a boolean condition...

Comment: Found!! The problem was in the caller!! Thanks !